Como elimino las selecciones del MultiSelect con React Select
tengo un problema, implemente el MultiSelect de React-Select y funciona pero cuando envió el formulario, no se resetean los valores seleccionados, continúan permaneciendo allí mientras que los otros input si se resetean.
EDIT: El que aplica el reset cuando envió el formulario es el Select, por el contrario el ColourSelect, deja los valores seleccionados y no se resetea.
Estoy iniciándome en Laravel Inertia React.
He probado varias cosas y nada, acá dejo el código, en lo que puedan ayudarme.
// resources/js/Components/ColourSelect.jsx
import chroma from 'chroma-js';
import Select from 'react-select';

const colourStyles = {
    control: (styles) => ({ ...styles, backgroundColor: 'white' }),
    option: (styles, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) => {
        const color = chroma(data.color || '#000');
        return {
            ...styles,
            backgroundColor: isDisabled
                ? undefined
                : isSelected
                    ? data.color
                    : isFocused
                        ? color.alpha(0.1).css()
                        : undefined,
            color: isDisabled
                ? '#ccc'
                : isSelected
                    ? chroma.contrast(color, 'white') > 2
                        ? 'white'
                        : 'black'
                    : data.color,
            cursor: isDisabled ? 'not-allowed' : 'default',

            ':active': {
                ...styles[':active'],
                backgroundColor: !isDisabled
                    ? isSelected
                        ? data.color
                        : color.alpha(0.3).css()
                    : undefined,
            },
        };
    },
    multiValue: (styles, { data }) => {
        const color = chroma(data.color || '#000');
        return {
            ...styles,
            backgroundColor: color.alpha(0.1).css(),
        };
    },
    multiValueLabel: (styles, { data }) => ({
        ...styles,
        color: data.color,
    }),
    multiValueRemove: (styles, { data }) => ({
        ...styles,
        color: data.color,
        ':hover': {
            backgroundColor: data.color,
            color: 'white',
        },
    }),
};

const ColourSelect = ({ value, onChange, options }) => (
    <Select
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        defaultValue={value}
        isMulti
        options={options}
        styles={colourStyles}
        onChange={onChange}
    />
);

export default ColourSelect;

Aquí esta la del Formulario:
// resources/js/Pages/Teacher/partials/Form.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Label, TextInput, Select} from 'flowbite-react';
import {useForm} from '@inertiajs/react';
import InputError from '@/Components/InputError';
import ColourSelect from '@/Components/ColourSelect';

const Form = ({errors, statuses, careers}) => {
    const {data, setData, post, processing, reset} = useForm({
        status_id: '',
        career_ids: []
    });


    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        post(route('teachers.store'), {onSuccess: () => reset()});
    };
    const getRandomColor = () => {
        const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        let color = '#';
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    };

    const careerOptions = careers.map(career => ({
        value: career.id,
        label: career.name,
        color: getRandomColor()
    }));

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit} className="flex flex-col gap-4">
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6">

                <div className="sm:col-span-2">
                    <div className="mb-2 block">
                        <Label htmlFor="status_id" value="Estatus"/>
                    </div>
                    <Select
                        id="status_id"
                        value={data.status_id}
                        onChange={e => setData('status_id', e.target.value)}
                        required
                    >
                        <option value='' disabled>Seleccione un estatus</option>
                        {Object.entries(statuses).map(([key, value]) => (
                            <option key={key} value={value}>{key.replace('STATUS_', '').toLowerCase()}</option>
                        ))}
                    </Select>
                    <InputError message={errors.status_id} className='mt-2'/>
                </div>

                <div className="sm:col-span-4">
                    <div className="mb-2 block">
                        <Label htmlFor="career_ids" value="Carreras"/>
                    </div>
                    <ColourSelect
                        value={data.career_ids.map(id => careerOptions.find(option => option.value === id))}
                        onChange={selectedOptions => setData('career_ids', selectedOptions.map(option => option.value))}
                        options={careerOptions}
                    />
                    <InputError message={errors.career_ids} className='mt-2'/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Button pill type="submit" disabled={processing}>Crear</Button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Form;

He probado este código generado por una inteligencia artificial y no me ha funcionado, ya que no se resetea los valores seleccionados:
const [selectedCareers, setSelectedCareers] = useState([]);

    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        post(route('teachers.store'), {
            onSuccess: () => {
                reset();
                setSelectedCareers([]); // Limpiar el ColourSelect
            }
        });
    };

 const handleCareerChange = (selectedOptions) => {
        setSelectedCareers(selectedOptions);
        setData('career_ids', selectedOptions.map(option => option.value));
    };

 <ColourSelect
             value={selectedCareers}
             onChange={handleCareerChange}
             options={careerOptions}
             />

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, gracias

Dentro de Form  se ven dos select, <Select id="status_id".../> y ColourSelect, ¿Cual no aplica reset a sus opciones?

El select aplica el reset el ColourSelect no

En el select con id=""status_id" se estan generando los options con su respectiva etiqueta con Object.entries(statuses).map pero en el ColourSelect se esta usando la prop options del Select y se esta pasando  carreroptions, ¿porque usas la prop options en ColourSelect en vez de crear el select de la misma forma que creas el select con id=""status_id"?
